# g++ complains constexpr function is not a constant expression

Tags: c++, g++, constant-expression

I've reduced my problem to the following:

```
struct A {
    static constexpr std::size_t f() { return 4; }
};

template<std::size_t N>
struct B : A {
    alignas(A::f()) char a[N];
};
```

I don't see what's wrong with this, yet if I try to compile using `g++`:

```
main.cpp:9:19: error: expression 'A::f' is not a constant-expression
     alignas(A::f()) char a[N];
                   ^
main.cpp:9: confused by earlier errors, bailing out
```

Reproduction is available [on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae455ebc47239ee7).

Comment: [This, perhaps?](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gcc.bugs/425219) GCC 5.1 gives me an ICE, though.

Comment: [The plot thickens...](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e4e9d42d7ee440a)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the original code is bad but here is a workaround:

```
struct A {
    static constexpr std::size_t f() { return  4; }
};

template<std::size_t ALIGN, std::size_t N>
struct C {
    alignas(ALIGN) char a[N];
};

template<std::size_t N>
struct B : A, C<A::f(), N> {
};
```